# Reactive Extensions: How to observe a IEnumerable method result async

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

i've a methode that return a IEnumerable of my business object. In this method i parse the content of a large text file to the business object model. There is no threading stuff in it.

In my ViewModel (WPF) i need to store and display the results of the method. 
Store is an ObservableCollection.

Here ist the observable code:

```
private void OpenFile(string file)
{
    _parser = new IhvParser();
    App.Messenger.NotifyColleagues(Actions.ReportContentInfo, new Model.StatusInfoDisplayDTO { Information = "Lade Daten...", Interval = 0 });

    _ihvDataList.Clear();

    var obs = _parser.ParseDataObservable(file)
                     .ToObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
                     .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                     .Subscribe<Ihv>(AddIhvToList, ReportError, ReportComplete);
}

private void ReportComplete()
{
    App.Messenger.NotifyColleagues(Actions.ReportContentInfo, new Model.StatusInfoDisplayDTO { Information = "Daten fertig geladen.", Interval = 3000 });
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => IhvDataList);
}

private void ReportError(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("...");
}

private void AddIhvToList(Ihv ihv)
{
    _ihvDataList.Add(ihv);
}
```

And this is the parser code:

```
public IEnumerable<Model.Ihv> ParseDataObservable(string file)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        var head = reader.ReadLine(); //erste Zeile ist Kopfinformation

        if (!head.Contains("BayBAS") || !head.Contains("2.3.0"))
        {
            _logger.ErrorFormat("Die Datei {0} liegt nicht im BayBAS-Format 2.3.0 vor.");
        }
        else
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line.Length != 1415)
                {
                    _logger.ErrorFormat("Die Datei {0} liegt nicht im BayBAS-Format 2.3.0 vor.");
                    break;
                }

                var tempIhvItem = Model.Ihv.Parse(line);
                yield return tempIhvItem;
            }
            reader.Close();

        }
    }

}
```

Why do i don't get the results async? Before i see the results in my DataGrid, all items are parsed and delivered.

Can anybody help?

Andreas

Comment: - What is the type of _ihvDataList?
- How long does it take to Parse a line?

Comment: I use the ObservableCollection for the _ihvDataList field.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure this isn't happening asynchronously?  Are you assuming this based on what you *perceive* in the UI, or have you set breakpoints and determined that this is, in fact, the case?

Note that WPF's `Dispatcher` uses a priority queue, and `DispatcherScheduler` schedules items with `Normal` priority, which trumps the priority levels used for input, layout, and rendering.  If the results come in quickly enough, then the UI may not get updated until after the last result has been processed: the dispatcher might be too busy processing results to perform layout and rendering of the UI.

You could try overriding the behavior of the `DispatcherScheduler` to schedule at a custom priority like so:

```
public class PriorityDispatcherScheduler : DispatcherScheduler
{
    private readonly DispatcherPriority _priority;

    public PriorityDispatcherScheduler(DispatcherPriority priority)
        : this(priority, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher) {}

    public PriorityDispatcherScheduler(DispatcherPriority priority, Dispatcher dispatcher)
        : base(dispatcher)
    {
        _priority = priority;
    }

    public override IDisposable Schedule<TState>(TState state, Func<IScheduler, TState, IDisposable> action)
    {
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        var d = new SingleAssignmentDisposable();

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            _priority,
            (Action)(() =>
                     {
                         if (d.IsDisposed)
                             return;
                         d.Disposable = action(this, state);
                     }));

        return d;
    }
}
```

And then modify your observable sequence by replacing `ObserveOnDispatcher()` with `ObserveOn(new PriorityDispatcherScheduler(p))`, where `p` is an appropriate priority level (e.g., `Background`).

**Also**, this looks highly suspect: `ToObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default)`.  I believe this will cause a new thread to be created every time a result comes in, for the sole purpose of passing it to the dispatcher, after which the new thread will terminate.  This is almost certainly not what you intended.  I assume you simply wanted the file processed on a separate thread; as written, your code would literally end up creating 1,000 short-lived threads if your `IEnumerable` yields 1,000 items, none of which would actually be doing the work of reading the file.

**Lastly**, is `OpenFile()` being invoked on the dispatcher thread?  If so, I believe what is going to happen is as follows:

1. Dispatcher (on UI thread) will call `Subscribe()`, which will process the chain of observable operators all the way back to `ParseDataObservable(file)`.
2. Dispatcher will iterate through your `IEnumerable` sequence, firing each result into the observable sequence created by `ToObservable()`.
3. Each result passed into the observable sequence will be scheduled for delivery on the dispatcher (the very same dispatcher that is *currently running*).

If this is the case, then the entire file will be read *before* any of the results get passed to `AddIhvToList()`, because the dispatcher is tied up reading the file and won't get around to processing the results in its queue until it has finished.  If this is what is happening, you can try altering your code as follows:

```
var obs = _parser.ParseDataObservable(file)
                 .ToObservable()
                 .SubscribeOn(/*NewThread*/Scheduler.Default)
                 .ObserveOnDispatcher() // consider using PriorityDispatcherScheduler
                 .Subscribe<Ihv>(AddIhvToList, ReportError, ReportComplete);
```

Injecting `SubscribeOn()` should ensure that the iteration of your `IEnumerable` (i.e., the reading of the file) occurs on a separate thread.  `Scheduler.Default` should suffice here, but you could use a `NewThreadScheduler` if you really need to (you probably don't).  The dispatcher thread will return from `Subscribe()` after everything has been set up, freeing it up to continue processing its queue, i.e., passing the results to `AddIhvToList()` as they come in.  This should give you the asynchronous behavior you desire.

Comment: Yes, it being async but fast is where I was going with my questions. Also wondered if the list isn't an INPC implementer. +1

Comment: The List Type is ObservableCollection. 


The NewThreadScheduler is the new Scheduler.Thread. This is obsolet (see documentation for more infos).


I will try the implementations described in the posts.

Comment: Yes, I know what `NewThreadScheduler` is.  It creates a new thread on every call to `Schedule()`, which is almost always undesirable.  `Scheduler.Default` will use the playform's preferred scheduling method (typically some sort of thread pool), and is usually preferable.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. Thanks for that useful information. I'll use the ThreadPoolScheduler.